Binary Logistic Regression with only one continious predictor and a small sample size: How to test for linearity?
I have a fitted binary model with 10 datapoints. The single continious variable is in the interval of [2.4, 4.4] with one binary output variable Y. Y contains 4 events with Y=1 and 6 with Y=0. The modelling worked fine when avoiding complete seperation. I used python.
I read many papers which stated that the assumptions of logistic regression ( (1)linearity: is the linear predictor correct?, (2) the logit transformation is the correct function linking the covariates with the conditional mean, and (3)the variance is Bernoulli) need to be checked.
My question is the following:
With only one predictor, what is the best way to check for linearity if even nessecary? Can I do that with classic GOF-tests when they are basically just testing whether there are any non-linearities or interactions that I missed?
If you need any more informations regarding my model, please let me know!

The questions focuses on logistic regression with a small sample size which is indeed helpful for people with that problem. It basically answers the question if modelling test data woth 10 entries even makes sense. So in that case it is only one main topic and should please be reopened for further input, thanks!

It's only one topic, but it's many questions.

@BenBolker I updated my question, sorry! Is it possible for you to answer my question down below as well? Would really appreciate it.

tl;dr having low sample size and a single predictor doesn't really let you off the hook about any assumptions. On the other hand, you won't be able to test the assumptions powerfully either (i.e. you won't be able to tell how badly the assumptions are violated).
With this small a sample size you should also keep in mind that the standard fitting procedure (GLM/maximum likelihood) and significance testing for logistic regression are asymptotic procedures, so might be especially unreliable. You might consider exact logistic regression (Wilson and Lorenz 2015; elrm package in R) or bias-reduced regression (e.g. Firth regression, brglm2 package in R) [sorry, I don't know whether there are Python equivalents or what they are].
Or run the logistic regression and take the results with a larger-than-usual grain of salt.


With only one predictor, do I need to check for linearity? Or on that matter: any of the assumptions? FYI: There is no way for me to include a second covariate.

Technically, yes (linearity checks are only unnecessary when you have only categorical predictors [and include all interactions]). On the other hand, checks of model adequacy will have very low power anyway ...

Do I need to test for significance of my variable when I only have one? It would mean that I test my model against the null model. This test, which is basically the Likelihood-Ratio-Test, will always tell me that my covariate is significant, right? So the test wouldn't give me any info?

If you don't have an intercept term in your model, it's probably not sensible (this is an issue with some Python tools which leave it up to you to add the intercept to the model matrix manually ...).  You should be comparing the models
$$
y_i \sim \textrm{Binomial}(p), \quad \textrm{logit}(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i
$$
with
$$
y_i \sim \textrm{Binomial}(p), \quad \textrm{logit}(p) = \beta_0
$$
which is certainly not always significant.

GOF-tests: Regarding the very first questions: When I just assume that my assumptions are met, do I even need to perform a classic GOF-Test like the Hosmer-Lemeshow-test? When the HL-Test is basically just testing whether there are any non-linearities or interactions that I missed and I concluded that they aren't any, can I just not perform the test? Is that valid with that reasoning? When it's not valid: which one is acceptable/ the best for a sample size of 10?

As mentioned above, (1) you are still assuming linearity (it's not automatically true and (2) any tests of model adequacy will have very low power. Furthermore, the Hosmer-Lemeshow test has low power in any case. Frank Harrell suggests alternatives.

Regarding the test for the predictive power: Which one is acceptable/ the best for a sample size of 10? Unfortunately, there is no way for me to gain more samples. I like the McFadden Pseudo R^2, it gives me a value of .41. Can I use it with such a small sample size?

All of the pseudo-R^2 measures are evaluating different things/answering different questions, I don't think there's a "best" one, nor that which one you want depends on sample size.

Wilson, Jeffrey R., and Kent A. Lorenz. 2015. “Exact Logistic Regression Model.” In Modeling Binary Correlated Responses Using SAS, SPSS and R, edited by Jeffrey R. Wilson and Kent A. Lorenz, 147–65. Cham: Springer International Publishing. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-23805-0_8.

+1. As an aside about the pseudo $R^2$ values, if I am doing logistic regression purely for binary classes as a response, then I think Tjur's $R^2$ of discrimination is the most intuitive to me, as it is a measure of the model's ability to correctly distinguish between classes (using the difference of average fitted values for successes and failures). Source here.

Thank you for the answer! Regarding testing the linearity: are GOF-tests acceptable for testing linearity, like the alternatives Frank Harrel suggests? (Even if every test has low power with the low sample size, I probably need to do it for my master thesis)
Regarding testing hte significance: I do have an intercept in my model (beta_0). Comparing the two models, one with my continious variable and one model without, can be done by the Likelihood-Ratio-Test, right?

One can say that the minimum sample size for a binary logistic model with zero predictors, i.e., only an intercept, is n=96.  That is the sample size needed to estimate $\Pr(Y=1)$ to within $\pm 0.1$ with 0.95 confidence level.  Adding predictors can only make the needed sample size increase from 96.

I read that in your book but it sparked a couple questions:
'predicted probability is within 0.1 of the true probability with 0.95 confidence' --> What is the 'true probability' by your definition?
And why should the margin of error not exceed 0.1 for either value of x? Why exactly 0.1? I probably just missed the exact reason for this in the book, would you mind telling me again?

In this no-covariate case this reduces to the one-sample binomial problem.  Read about confidence intervals and margins of error for such problems.  You can start with this.  Margin of error = $\frac{1}{2}$ width of confidence interval.  The true probability is $\Pr(Y=1)$ unconditional on $X$ in this case.
